# Random timeout error with Pika and gevent

Tags: python, rabbitmq, gevent, pika

I've been trying to make use of RabbitMQ from within my gevent program by using the Pika library (monkey patched by gevent), gevent likes randomly throwing a timeout error.

What should I do? Is there another library I could use?

```
WARNING:root:Document not found, retrying primary.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 32, in __init__
    BaseConnection.__init__(self, parameters, None, reconnection_strategy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 50, in __init__
    reconnection_strategy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 170, in __init__
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 228, in _connect
    self.parameters.port or  spec.PORT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 44, in _adapter_connect
    self._handle_read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 151, in _handle_read
    data = self.socket.recv(self._suggested_buffer_size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 427, in recv
    wait_read(sock.fileno(), timeout=self.timeout, event=self._read_event)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 169, in wait_read
    switch_result = get_hub().switch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 164, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
timeout: timed out
```

Comment: I'm facing up the same issue when I use 2 or more producers in one green thread only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pika is not ideally suited to use with gevent because pika implements its own asynchronous connection to RabbitMQ based on non-blocking sockets. This just does not fit well with gevent's implementation of the same.

You may want to consider using [py-amqplib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/amqplib/1.0.2) or [kombu](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/kombu/0.9.1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having timeout problems with using Pika in a Django/Gunicorn application. I played with raising `connection_attempts` or increasing the timeout but RabbitMQ always closed the connection with a handshake error. The latter seems to indicate that Pika never transmitted any data on the socket.

The cause for the timeouts could be this [libevent bug](http://code.google.com/p/gevent/issues/detail?id=97) - at least in my environment the script attached to the bug is able to reproduce the issue.

You could try upgrading to gevent>=1.0 (at the time of writing not released yet):

```
wget http://gevent.googlecode.com/files/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz
pip install gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz
```

Comment: Tried to use ```gevent-1.0.1``` - no luck.